# How to remove Duplicate Spaces from my Headline?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a long string to use in headline in a text label and i have some extra spaces. I want to delete these multiple spaces but staying only one. For example "  stack over flow is     nice" should return " stack over flow is nice"

I write this function :

```
func headlineFixer(headline: String) -> String {
    let components = headline.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

It seems okay but there is trick. It prints "stack over flow is nice" but i was expecting to
" stack over flow is nice"
How can i fix this or is there any way achieve this. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all even if your solution was true, it would not be perfect approach. Because your approach contains too many loops even if seems short and nice at first glance

You could do a for loop by checking " " and appending a variable string type.

Hopefully Swift has a method for Strings called [replacingOccurrences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences). By using this method and adding of `+` in front of space you would handle this issue.

```
func clearWay(input: String) -> String {
    return input.replacingOccurrences(of: " +", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
}
    
print(clearWay(input: "  stack over flow is     nice"))

// result is: stack over flow is nice
// just like you wish
```